# STM32 I2C Receive Function Size Parameter Problem

Tags: c++, c, stm32, i2c

I am working on STM32G474RET6 MCU in i2c slave mode. I want to make a polling mode with DMA but the problem is i don't know the receiving data's length. Every time it can be different. But 'HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_DMA(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size)' function takes size parameter.

I tried to give the size parameter buffer size. And for example i gave 20 as a parameter but get 5 byte data.When i do that, it takes the whole data to the buffer but hi2c state stays busy and it does get into ErrorCallback instead of RxCompltdCallback.

I tried to give the size 1 and takes the data one by one. It takes the data. But it overwrites the data in the same column of the buffer itself and in the end i can only take the last byte. And also again it goes into ErrorCallback.

Is there any way I can communicate without knowing the size parameter?

Comment: How do you know the data size? Is there an "end of data" byte value or is the data length encoded in the data or ...?

Comment: @nielsen even if. How can DMA use this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DMA in this situation is possible, but, as suggested, you will need some kind of I2C interrupt as well. The problem is to say when the last byte arrived without having CPU actually look at every incoming byte one by one, otherwise what's the point of DMA, you can go with interrupts (could be perfectly valid option)

Your problem boils down to "I receive arbitrary number of bytes at a time as I2C slave, how do I know the transmission has ended".

I will use STM32F103 (used in Blue Pills and Nucleo boards) as an example, since I have its documentation at hand. Its I2C has STOPF bit, which in slave mode serves as stop event detection bit, and it can trigger an interrupt - exactly what we need.

I propose the following logic:

1. Configure I2C with DMA reception, DMA transfer length 0xFFFFFFFF (maximum)
2. Configure I2C event interrupts
3. Let DMA receive *n* bytes (arbitrary)
4. In I2C event interrupt handler (triggered by detecting STOP bit as I2C slave) you check the remaining DMA transfer data length (e.g. 0xFFFFFFFD), which means you received 0xFFFFFFFF - 0xFFFFFFFD = 2 bytes = *n*.
5. Process *n* bytes, reset DMA transfer length to max value.

Comment: master does not have to send STOP. It can be  also START

Comment: Start also triggers interrupt. If a slave is supposed to reply to repeated start, it can be handled too. I assumed simple read/write sequences without repeated start, but repeated start is not a problem as well.

Comment: I know that  it trigers. My comment was to add it in your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes i followed your way and it worked. Its still goes into errorCallback but i'm not sure anymore i can prevent this situation. It goes into errorCallback and error situation shows ACKF error but doesn't block my communication.
For second option i am also trying to take byte by byte this. But with dma i can't stop the process. Even if i put 1 or 20 it takes the whole data not the first byte. Do you know something about that?

Comment: I can't possibly know why you have some error. Check what it means in the reference manual, try different test messages and see when error happens and when it doesn't. Could be repeated start thing, could be something else. With I2C, you really need a logic analyzer to make life comfortable (will be helpful further on as well). As for the second question, I have honestly no idea what you said, I didn't understand what you meant. I don't understand what process you're trying to stop, and what exactly "the whole data" is. Please, ask a full detailed question. Possibly, as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mix I2C interrupts and DMA in the same code.

You need to have I2C interrupt handler waiting for NACK, START and STOP events and then you know that the transmission has finished. DMA driver will not provide you with this information as it triggers the interrupt if all (or/and [if half interrupts are enabled] half) expected bytes have been transferred.